# Log Transformation of Sample Values

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

> Suppose a random sample of measurements $T_1,T_2,...,T_{10}$ is drawn from the distribution of $T$, and after $\log$ transformation of the sample values $\bar X=\frac1{10}(\sum_{i=1}^{10}X_i)$ is obtained. If $\mu=1.25$ and $\sigma=0.005$, what is the value of $P(\bar X>1.26)\;(4$dp$)$?

Hi,

I'm unsure how to answer this question. I've tried using Normal Distribution but I'm getting a $z-$score of $-14.409$ which is not on the standard table.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you getting a $z$-score of $-14.409$? Please show us your working and see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Why have you tried using the Normal distribution? The question does not specify that. It asks for an exact answer, and in any event, the sample is not large enough to assume CLT. The question appears ill-conceived to me, or is missing relevant information.